# Is this kind of array declaration legal?

Tags: c++, arrays

I know that in C++ you cannot declare the size the array with a run-time variable, but I am interested in making sure whether the following would be legal:

```
#include directives 
const int SIZE=5;
double a[SIZE];
```

Thank you!!

Comment: It is valid. did you get any error?

Comment: @Vikdor No. I was in the middle of a very large program and I just wanted to make sure, so I don't need to use `#define`. Thank you! :)

Comment: @Vokram, C++11 has `constexpr` for that. It goes beyond what `const` does for you in regards to constant expressions.

Comment: Makes sense. I would just open an editor and write those three lines, enclosing two of them in a main function and see what compiler has to say :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is legal in C++ and C both.

`SIZE` needs to be a ***constant expression*** and in C++ `const int SIZE=5;` declares it so.
In C prior to introduction of variable length arrays in C99,

```
const int SIZE=5;
double a[SIZE];
```

would yield a error because in this case `SIZE` is not a ***constant expression*** but merely ***readonly*** and it needs to be a constant expression to be valid.